# Should I store string values in variables or as hidden input value

Tags: javascript, dom, variables

Is there a difference, in terms of efficiency, whether to store string values in variables or as a content of hidden input elements? Those values could be large and could be modified frequently.

Comment: The real question is: *does it belong in the DOM*? If it does, leave it. If not, take it out. Don't worry about "efficiency": however, variables will be faster and will likely use less memory, f.s.v.o. (In reality, It Just Doesn't matter.)

Comment: What's the purpose? If you're submitting those values with a form then it makes sense to have them in the DOM. If you're only using them as temporary storage for a script or something else, then a variables-only approach seems sufficient.

Comment: @Cory I submit the value, but rarely. The value itself changes frequently though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have a reason to store values in input elements, it's much better to use variables, in terms of both speed and memory consumption.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a good reason to store a value in an input field. Its may take time to query the DOM to retrieve an input value. So storing a value in a variable will be easier to retrieve and modify.